# DART find all the fields in class

Tags: dart

Can some provide an example how to obtain all the fields in giving class?

For example:

```
class A{
  String aa;
  String bb;
  static String ss;
  string simple(){
    return 'simple';
  }
  getallMemberFields(){
   // returun ["aa", "bb"]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about reflection, here is an example of how to get not only variable and function names, but also some extra info about them

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A {
  String aa;
  String bb;
  static String ss;
  String simple() {
    return 'simple';
  }

  getallMemberFields() {
    // returun ["aa", "bb"]
  }
}

void main() {
  InstanceMirror instance_mirror = reflect(new A());
  var class_mirror = instance_mirror.type;

  for (var v in class_mirror.declarations.values) {
    var name = MirrorSystem.getName(v.simpleName);

    if (v is VariableMirror) {
      print('Variable: $name');
      print(
          'Static: ${v.isStatic}, Private: ${v.isPrivate}, Final: ${v.isFinal}, Const: ${v.isConst}');
    } else if (v is MethodMirror) {
      print('Method: $name');
      print(
          'Static: ${v.isStatic}, Private: ${v.isPrivate}, Abstract: ${v.isAbstract}');
    }
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
Variable: aa
Static: false, Private: false, Final: false, Const: false
Variable: bb
Static: false, Private: false, Final: false, Const: false
Variable: ss
Static: true, Private: false, Final: false, Const: false
Method: simple
Static: false, Private: false, Abstract: false
Method: getallMemberFields
Static: false, Private: false, Abstract: false
Method: A
Static: false, Private: false, Abstract: false
```

Comment: It works great. Thanks for answer the question in Christmas! Happy New year!

Comment: And of course, the two problems with using mirrors is that (a) it won't work on Flutter, ever, and (b) it inflates your code because tree-shaking is no longer possible.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz is there an alternative available?