# How to get all static const fields of a Dart class without using mirrors?

Tags: flutter, dart, reflection

I know, this question is very similar to [DART find all the fields in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917890/dart-find-all-the-fields-in-class). I wonder if there is any way to achieve this without using mirrors?

My use case is the following: I use the [shared_preferences package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store many values. For the keys I have a class like this:

```dart
class Key {
  static const String FOO = 'foo';
  static const String BAR = 'bar';
  ...
}
```

I want to write a unit test that checks, that this class of constants does not contains any duplicates. The following would leed to bugs:

```dart
class Key {
  static const String FOO = 'foo';
  static const String BAR = 'bar';
  static const String ANOTHER = 'foo';
}
```

Since `dart:mirrors` does not work here, what is the best way to implement the test?

Comment: I don't think there's anything that prevents you from using `dart:mirrors` for a unit test.  Otherwise you would need to use [`package:analyzer`](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer).

Comment: @jamesdlin I get `Target of URI doesn't exist: 'dart:mirrors' if I try to import the package.

Comment: If you can make your `Key` class a pure Dart package that doesn't depend on Flutter, then you should be able to use `dart:mirrors` in its own tests.  You also can look into using [`package:reflectable`](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable).

Comment: My key class has no imports. Its just a bunch of constants. My test class also have no imports to flutter. It just imports `import 'package:test/test.dart';`.

Comment: But your `Key` class probably isn't its own *package*; it presumably is in a package whose `pubspec.yaml` has a Flutter dependency.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you mean. But creating an own package for a few constants may not be worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

If your keys happen to follow the syntax for naming variables, you can use an `enum` instead of a class:

```dart
enum Key { foo, bar }
```

After you swap out your class for the enum, replace references to `Key.FOO` and `Key.BAR` with `Key.foo.name` and `Key.bar.name` respectively. And as a bonus, using an enum means you don't have to test for duplicate keys!

Dart 2.17 (released May 11, 2022) introduced "enhanced enums". Feel free to check out this [article](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-17-b216bfc80c5d) or the [Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types) for an in-depth description of what you can do.

If you want to be able to use any string as a key, you can make an enhanced enum:

```dart
enum Key {
  foo('multiple words'),
  bar('punctuation!');

  final String keyname;
  const Key(this.keyname);

  @override
  String toString() => keyname;
  String call() => keyname;
}

bool noDuplicates() {
  final List<String> keys = [for (final k in Key.values) k()];
  return keys.length == keys.toSet().length;
}
```

`toString()` and `call()` aren't necessary, but they can be convenient for when you want to represent the key as `"${Key.foo}"` or `Key.foo()` instead of having to use `Key.foo.keyname`.